# How to await callback function to finished?

Tags: javascript, function, callback, promise

I have two simple functions:A function which returns a `promise`

```
function showBootbox(){
   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
       bootbox.confirm('Are you sure ? ',resolve);
   });  
}
```

and a function which uses a `callback`.

```
function getBootboxValue(callback) {
   showBootbox().then(function (result) {
      callback(result);
   });
}
```

Now the problem is that i can't await for callback to finished.

```
if(condition){
  getBootboxValue(function(result){
    if(result){
       //code
    }
  });
}
console.log('a');
```

`console.log(a)` is executing before I got the result of promise. How can I do this without using `async/await` mechanism ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: " i can't await for callback to finished" but you have to. If something goes async it "infects" the rest of your code. Nothing (not even async/await which is just a sugar to handle promises) could magically turn async code into sync one. So you have to move log part into callback or return a Promise from `getBootboxValue`.

Comment: Of course the `console.log` will run first, it's outside the callback. If you want anything to run afterwards it needs to be inside that callback.

Comment: @BenShelton, i updated my code. I have the callback inside of a condition and then i have a lot of code then

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, I have to await the result and if it's false then returns from function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I didn't get it wrong, your idea is to `console.log('a')` immidiately if the condition is not met and `console.log('a')` at the end of the callback if the condition is met.

If that is so, one option could be to return the promise of `getBootboxValue(callback)` when the condition is met and an already fulfilled promise if the condition is not met. You'd then use a callback for that promise that would contain the `console.log('a')`.

```js
function showBootbox() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('Are you sure ? ');
    resolve();
  });
}

function getBootboxValue(callback) {
  return showBootbox().then(function(result) {
    callback(result);
  });
}

function test(condition) {
  var cbk = function(result) {
      console.log('Launching callback');
      if (result) {
        //code
      }
    },
    aux = condition ? getBootboxValue(cbk) : Promise.resolve(null);

  aux.then(function() {
    console.log('a')
  });
}

test(true);
test(false);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are after. If you need to conditionally execute an async function and then run some code else run that code anyway you can put the code in a function and call it in either situation:

```
if(condition){
  getBootboxValue(function(result){
    if(result){
       //code
    }
    doSomething();
  });
} else {
  doSomething();
}
function doSomething() {
  console.log('a');
}
```

Comment: i know that's possible , but i want the solution without invoke the function twice. Anyway, +1.